# Preposition before noun phrases - omission of "in"

Tags: prepositions

I have seen in some cases prepositions are omitted before some noun phrases. And it's explained that those phrases are actually an adverb phrases. But I know a simple thing. If the head of the phrase is a noun, it's a noun phrase. If the head of the phrase is an adverb it is an adverb phrase.

For example -

> 1. Look **both ways** before crossing the road. [**both ways** is a noun phrase, where the head is **ways**, but still there is no preposition.]
> 2. He approached me *in* **a friendly way**. [**a friendly way** is a noun phrase, where the head is **way**, but as expected unlike sentence #1 it's preceded by the preposition **in**. And I have never seen this phrase is used without a preposition. I believe dropping the preposition is wrong, according to the grammar.]
> 3. She made a pickle **a different way** from her mother. [**a different way** is a noun phrase, where the head is **way**, but strangely there is no preposition before it. But I have seen examples of **a different way** used both with prepositions and without prepositions. I think the preposition here is optional.]

Now from these example sentences I have tried to demonstrate my problem/confusing area. My question is -

**1.** When a noun phrase is used as an adverb phrase?

**2.** When before a noun phrase the placement of preposition is obligatory (like sentence #2)? And where it's optional (like sentence #3)? And where placing the preposition is wrong (like sentence #1)?

Comment: Way #1 = a path or direction.  Way #2 = manner.  When it means "manner" use the preposition (it won't be incorrect even if it is not necessary). When it is directional, don't use a preposition.  He looked each way before crossing the street.  She sings the song (in) a different way.

Comment: @TRomano Well, but it's not true for **a friendly way**, I am very sure dropping a preposition before that phrase is incorrect. Not only that I have never seen that phrase with **friendly** used without a preposition.

Comment: What's not true?  I said to use the preposition when "way" means "manner".  He spoke to the stranger in a friendly way.

Comment: Perhaps you need this clarification: ... even if it is not *always* necessary..."?

Comment: @TRomano hmm..sorry for not being clear. Let me be clear. Yes **way** is a noun where it means **manner**. When we form NP like **a friendly way** or **a different way**, *way* means *manner*. But the thing is we can write **He did it (in) a different way**, but not **He approached me a friendly way**.

Comment: OK. I see. Your question is academic, not pragmatic.

Comment: "way" is a noun in either case.  The phrase is basically adverbial in both cases: `.... each way...in a friendly way` inasmuch as it modifies or describes the verb.

Comment: @TRomano True. Actually that realization made me ask this question. You remember there was a similar question **the same way vs in the same way**. I wrote an answer there stating that **the same way** is an adverb phrase, but then I deleted the answer. The reason is it is always told that the head should be adverbial to make it adverbial phrase. Here it is not the case. Still I know an NP can act as an adverbial. And that is very tricky for a non native speakers. (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) One new learner can figure out, well, **a different way** is a NP acting as an adverbial. So he is left with the choice of either placing a preposition before it or drop it. But he can consider **a friendly way** same way. An NP acting as an adverbial, but here he is not left with any choice. He need to use a preposition before it, obligatory :O

Comment: Using a preposition will never be incorrect when "way" means "manner", even if there are times when the preposition could be dropped with a particular phrase.  Dropping the preposition is a characteristic of colloquial speech; it is not usually dropped in writing of a formal nature by fluent native speakers although you may find examples where the preposition is dropped if the author is aiming for a casualness of tone and is imitating the easygoing manner of informal speech, or when the author is not even cognizant of such changes of register. A good writer is aware of the difference in tone.

Comment: @TRomano True. Always using the preposition here is safe, but I still want to know when they can be optional. Another reason I am asking because an NP can act as an adverbial. **next morning** is a NP, where the head **morning** is a noun, and **next** is a modifier (adjective). But using preposition before it is wrong - **I am not going to work o̶n̶  the next morning**.

Comment: You asked four questions. None of them is phrased as a question. Maybe you could first attend to basic matters like that, and then ponder the weightier matters of adverbial noun phrases.

Comment: We can't say in both ways. According to The Free Dictionary,  the phrase both ways is an adjective/adverb.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that without a preposition after an object pronoun, such as *me* above, it can sound like you might be trying to express an indirect or second object for the verb in question - especially if a noun is following.  If an adverb or adjective follows, there is no confusion.  Verbs that take indirect objects generally mean "to give" so the reader/listener may try to twist the meaning of what you say toward that.

> She kicked me hard <- Hard is an modifier, no confusion
>
> She kicked me to the curb <- "To" makes this clear, no confusion.
>
> She kicked me the curb <- Sounds like you're saying she physically kicked a curb towards you.
>
> He approached me a friendly way <- Sounds like you might be trying to say in a weird way that you were brought over or towards to "a friendly way" - whatever is meant by that.

If a noun is in between, it's at least somewhat OK - I would recommend using the preposition for maximum clarity.

> She made me a pickle [in] a different way

Comment: Not much what I was expecting. Well, still good input. But the thing is I already know these, please refer to those comments below the question for understanding what exactly I am looking for :-) thanks...

Comment: "an modifier".. was that a typo?

Answer (score 2):

### When is a noun phrase an adverb phrase?

Let us begin by addressing your first question. The descriptor *noun phrase* refers, per Wikipedia, to "**a phrase which has a noun (or indefinite pronoun) as its head word, or which performs the same grammatical function as such a phrase**." Similarly, Merriam Webster tells us that a noun phrase is "formed by a noun and all its modifiers and determiners," or "any syntactic element...with a noun's function (as the subject of a verb or the object of a verb or preposition."

Now, a head word is the word that **determines the syntactic role** (part of speech) played by the phrase. Thus the general usage defines a noun phrase by its function: if it acts like a noun, it is a noun phrase. Note that Merriam-Webster's first definition instead defines a noun phrase as simply having a noun.

On the other hand, what does Wikipedia have to say about adverbial phrases?

> "An adverbial phrase is a group of two or more words operating
> adverbially, meaning that their syntactic function is to modify a
> verb, an adjective, or an adverb."

Note that, as is generally the case with a  noun phrase, an adverbial phrase is *solely* defined by its role. Consider the following sentences.

> The Democatic debate is  **today**.
>
> We shall have a new president **in two years**.
>
> I'll be so relieved
> **when the election is over**.

We have three types of modifier here. The first is simply an adverb. The second is an adverb phrase. The third is an adverb phrase that happens to be an entire clause, or an *adverbial clause*. Observe that the adverb phrase contains a preposition, an adjective, and a noun: no adverb in sight. Indeed, many if not most adverb phrases are like this. Containing an adverb is not enough to make something an adverbial phrase: the whole phrase must function as an adverb, modifying an adjective, a verb, or another adverb.

So, what is the gist of the previous discussion? Generally, **both noun and verb phrases are defined by function**. Under this definition, the answer to "When is a noun phrase used as an adverb phrase?" is **never**. However, going by Merriam-Webster's first definition, which is more relevant to your question, the answer is **whenever it modifies an adjective, verb, or adverb**.

### When is it necessary to place a preposition before a noun phrase used as an adverb?

Unfortunately, as in many such cases, it is unlikely that one rule prescribes when one should use or avoid prepositions in adverbial phrases.

**Distance between the verb and the adverb phrase might be one factor:**

> She made the pickle a different way.

This sentence is unambiguous and fairly natural.

> She made the pickle, with peppercorns and dill, sealed in an enormous jar, a different way.

This sentence is ambiguous, because "a different way" could either refer to "with peppercorns and dill, sealed in an enormous jar" or to something else entirely. It also sounds awkward. However, if we write

> She made the pickle, with peppercorns and dill, sealed in an enormous jar, in a different way.

This is unambiguous (although the meaning would change if the adverb phrase were placed directly after "pickle." Also, "in a different manner" would probably be better here, but that is mostly a vocabulary choice.

Similarly, either "in a friendly way" or "a friendly way" would be appropriate in your second sentence. The use of a preposition is not really obligatory. However, if we separate "approach" and "friendly way" far apart, the sentence becomes clumsy and requires a preposition to avoid ambiguity.

**A second factor is whether the noun phrase can actually stand alone as a noun.** Consider your "both ways" example. This sentence makes no sense, at least in my dialect:

> Look to both ways before you cross the road.

Similarly with

> Look to up before you walk near that building under construction.

or

> Look at around when you cross the street.

The preposition is effectively prohibited in these cases, because it gives the impression that the adverb or adverb phrase could stand alone as a noun, which is not the case. Essentially, "both ways" and similar phrases have been used so long that they have become one adverb in people's minds, thus the inappropriateness of a preposition.

This is probably the most important "rule." When words have become associated in an frequently used adverbial noun phrase, it seems extremely awkward to add a preposition: "both ways," "this way," "the hard way." In fact, many such phrases have become so common that they arguably should be classified as compound adverbs, not noun phrases. As Khan noted in a comment, The Free Dictionary classifies "both ways" as an adverb (or occasional adjective), as indeed does Dictionary.com.

You will rarely encounter someone who says: "Do you want to do this in the easy way, or in the hard way?"

But when **such an association does not exist**, a preposition is generally required. This is acceptable.

> They arrived with an incredible noise.

This is not:

> They arrived an incredible noise.

In fact, it may be that the ability to stand alone as a noun is the central factor here. What leads to awkwardness in this cases seems to be ambiguity. There is no chance of confusion when someone arrives "a confusing way." There is if someone arrives "a confusing fashion."

"Both ways," " a confusing way": these are not often seen out of their common role as adverb phrases. By contrast, "confusing fashion" is.

Another issue is which preposition is being elided (if indeed one is). "With" can rarely be omitted, as one of the previous examples showed, while "in" often can be

However, all these are merely heuristics. As other answerers have noted, **there is not one hard-and-fast rule, or indeed set of rules, for determining when a preposition is required, and when it is not.**

Comment: You seems to have a debilitating grammar illness, one symptom of which is using the terms *adverbial phrase* and *adverb phrase* interchangably.

Comment: Aracauria, what gives?

Comment: With respect, the interchangeable usage is well-attested. See, e.g. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adverb_phrase.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit rude.

Comment: I understand that you would rather avoid the term "adverbial," referring instead to "adjuncts." Incidentally, your suggestion that "adverbial" be restricted to referring to adjuncts is, I think, a rule that I mostly followed in my answer.  I suspect, based on your previous discourse on this topic, that you would prefer that I use "noun phrase" and similar words to refer only to the nature of the head word, not syntactic function. Unfortunately, "noun phrase" is used in the other sense, shall we say, rather frequently.

Comment: I am not a great friend of prescriptivism, not only when it comes to the vernacular, but indeed linguistic or grammatical terms themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected that wikipedia entry. If you use the term adverbial it implies that when you use the term adverb phrase you're talking about a phrase with an adverb in. My comment was tongue in cheek as I hoped the language would imply. But there's a serious point. I can live with people using the term *adverbial* and even people who use NP to refer to a phrase with a type function as opposed to an actual type of phrase ...

Comment: ... because they *can* be used consistently. It's very confusing for learners  though if you start using adverbial and adverb phrase in the same piece of writing when there's not an adverb in sight. Imagine what it's like when some actual adverbs crop up ... :(

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment on your example (3). You say:

> She made a pickle a different way from her mother. [a different way is
>   a noun phrase, where the head is way, but strangely there is no
>   preposition before it. But I have seen examples of a different way
>   used both with prepositions and without prepositions. I think the
>   preposition here is optional.]

As an educated native speaker of American English, I find "She made a pickle a different way" to be unidiomatic. It sounds wrong. Americans and British speakers would say "She makes pickles differently from her mother" or "She makes pickles in a different way."

A preposition is usually correct before "way" where "way" means "manner." Idiomatically often the preposition is skipped. In "He did it the hard way," the preposition would actually seem wrong because it is so un-idiomatic, but in most cases where the preposition is commonly skipped, as in "He did it the same way," that is considered a good shorthand way of saying "He did it in the same way."

Answer (score 1):

> Look down both ways before crossing.
>   Look to both ways before crossing.
>   Look at both ways before crossing.

Prepositions don't seem forbidden in this case.   Awkward, perhaps, and unusual, but not impossible.

> He approached me a friendly way.
>   He approached me a different way.
>   He approached me that way.

Prepositions don't seem required in this case.   Again, we have varying degrees of unusualness and awkwardness, but these all seem possible.

It looks like "way" has this adverbial use (or licenses a null preposition, if you prefer) regardless of context.

Comment: the second set of examples is not really valid, I think. There has to be an "in"  after me to make the sentences correct.

Comment: None of the "ways" examples work in my idiolect, nor does the first "approached" example.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, when the function word "way" is used to describe manner or direction the preposition "in" is often omitted in certain positions, i.e. at the end of the sentence or after verbs. I discovered this phenomenon and collected some material to have a closer look at it. Sometimes the word "way" is lacking, too.

Examples

- 1 Idiom: to have the head screwed on right. - Derived from: in the right way.
- 2 Haramis loved the land as if it were her own child. In a way, it was. -
  Marion Zimmer-Bradley, Lady of The Trillium, page 2; fantasy. - At the beginning of a sentence no shortening.
- 3 Nobody in the Royal family knew that Aya's sister worked for the Archimage, and Haramis wanted to keep it that way. - from the same novel, page 7. - Shortened from: in that way. At the end of the sentence the drop of the preposition occurs very often.
- 4 She just did not want to live this way. Marion Zimmer-Bradley (MZB).-
- 5 Something wicked this way comes. Fantasy novel by Ray Bradbury. - Sense of "this way": towards us/in our direction.

Answer (score 1):

The noun in question, '**way**', can be used in a number of different senses. [Mirriam-Webster's Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way) lists at least twelve, not counting idiomatic expressions.

Many of those senses, such as #2 and #7, contain within them prepositional attributes. The 2nd one contains the idea of '**from**' and the 7th contains the idea of '**along**'.  When these senses are meant by a speaker, dropping the preposition is possible because the word '**way**' itself already contains those ideas.

Your distinction between noun phrase and adverbial is not exactly on point. When one restores the missing preposition, turning a plain noun phrase into a prepositional phrase, that prepositional phrase is being used adverbially, i.e., to modify a verb.

> Look ***along the road*** before crossing (it).
>
> He approached me in ***the manner of friend***.
>
> She made a pickle ***differently*** from her mother.

These are undoubtedly prepositional phrases used adverbially, or simple adverbs as in the last case.  In the first and third cases this adverbial sense is contained within the word '**way**'.  In the second case, it is not, the sense is that of a simple mode of acting, so the preposition is required.

Generally, if that subtle prepositional/adverbial sense is not included in your meaning when using that word, '**way**', the preposition should be explicitly included, else, it may be omitted.  I don't believe there is an explicit official rule.

Answer (score 1):

Adverbials are realized by a number of linguistic structures -

> **1.** She telephoned *(just) then*. **[Adverb Phrase with closed class adverbs as head]**
>
> **2.** She telephoned *(very) recently*. **[Adverb Phrase with open class adverbs as head]**
>
> **3.** She telephoned *last week*. **[Noun Phrase]**
>
> **4.** She telephoned *in the evening*. **[Prepositional Phrase]**
>
> **5.** She telephoned *though obviously ill*. **[Verbless clause]**
>
> **6.** She telephoned *while waiting for the plane*. **[Nonfinite clause]**
>
> **7.** She telephoned *hoping for a job*. **[Nonfinite clause]**
>
> **8.** She telephoned *to ask for an interview*. **[Nonfinite clause]**
>
> **9.** She telephoned *angered at the delay*. **[Nonfinite clause]**
>
> **10.** She telephoned *after she had seen the announcement*. **[Finite clause]**

In a survey -

Total number of adverbials - 10981 
**Realization Type -** 
**I)** Prepositional Phrases - 4414 
**II)** Closed class items - 3948 
**III)** Open class adverbs and adverb phrases - 1070 
**IV)** Finite clauses - 980 
**V)** Nonfinite and verbless clauses - 346 
**VI)** Noun phrases - 227

**Adverbials** are of four types - 
i) Adjunct 
ii) Subjunct 
iii) Disjunct 
iv) Conjunct

In all the example sentences I quoted in my question, the bold parts are adjuncts.

> **11.** Look **both ways** before crossing the road.

The bold part is an obligatory adjunct denoting direction. A directional or special adjunct can be realized by Noun phrase or by prepositional phrases. In this particular example it's Noun phrase. And it can be considered as a direct object to the verb **look**.

> **12.** He approached me **in a friendly way**. 
> **13.** She made a pickle **a different way** from her mother.

Both in sentence #12 and #13, the bold part is the adjunct of manner. In sentence #12 it's realized by a prepositional phrase, and in sentence #13 it's realized by a noun phrase.

Now the important question comes when we use a noun phrase and when we use a prepositional phrase.

Not all nouns can be used in this way, for example if we rewrite sentence #13 replacing *way* with the similar meaning word *manner*, it's wrong. We have to use a prepositional phrase then.

> **14.** She made a pickle **a different manner** from her mother. [INCORRECT]
>
> **15.** She made a pickle **in a different manner** from her mother. [CORRECT]

In sentence #11, it's wrong to use a preposition phrase there. Generally **both ways** don't take a preposition to express adjunct of direction. We however can use a prepositional phrase to express adjunct of direction.

> Looked at another way.

Comment: The survey is interesting! It'd be nice if you could add a link.

Comment: @DamkerngT. It's taken from *A Comprehensive Grammar of English Language*. page no. 489